# How to check what files exist in directory?

Tags: delphi, text-files, delphi-7

How can I check which text files are in a directory in Delphi 7. So that I can open all text files in my folder.

Answer (score 10):

There are a couple of different ways:

1. you can use the `FindFirst()` and `FindNext()` functions in the `System.SysUtils` unit.

   ```
   uses
     ..., SysUtils;

   var
     sr: TSearchRec;
   begin
     if FindFirst('C:\folders\*.txt', faAnyFile, sr) = 0 then
     try
       repeat
         if (sr.Attr and faDirectory) = 0 then
         begin
           // use sr.Name as needed...
         end;
       until FindNext(sr) <> 0;
     finally
       FindClose(sr);
     end;
   end;
   ```
2. if you are using Delphi 2010 or later, you can use the `GetFiles()` method of the `TDirectory` class in the `System.IOUtils` unit.

   ```
   uses
     ..., System.IOUtils;

   var
     files: TStringDynArray;
     filename: string;
   begin
     files := TDirectory.GetFiles('C:\Folder', '*.txt');
     for filename in files do
     begin
       // use filename as needed...
     end;
   end;
   ```

Comment: Is this code for delphi 7 or 8 as i don't have System.IOUtils

Comment: Delphi 8 is the .net preview. You didn't mention a Delphi version in your question.

Comment: The `System.IOUtils` unit was introduced in Delphi 2010.